# Pass secrets to post build actions

Tags: security, jenkins, post-build

I need to use a secret file in a post-build action in a Jenkins job. I'm using plain bash scripts and can't use Jenkinsfiles for some reasons.

But

> The credentials plugin cannot use secret file env variables in any
>   post build step. The secret files are deleted by the time post build
>   actions are run.

The issue is described here https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32283

What are available workarounds?

Comment: Using Jenkins pipeline scripts we can achieve this.

Comment: @RamakrishnaYelduti. Thanks. I added a clarification that I use plain bash scripts and can't use pipelines in this particular case.

Comment: You can make copy of secret file before post build action and use that copy in your post build actions.

Comment: @AmitNanaware
As an option. Current approach:
* code a secret as a base64 string

* write the string to a file

* decode the string in a post build step